# C# UWP - OnNavigatedTo fires methods twice

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there any alternative or workaround (such as break) to this event? If i try to navigate to `Form B` from `Form A`, then go back to `Form B`, my event (which is a DB Retrieve Method) Fires twice.

Code:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        EQList.ItemsSource = App.CALAMITY_VIEW_MODEL.GetEarthquakes();
        cbCalamities.ItemsSource = App.CALAMITY_VIEW_MODEL.GetEarthquakes();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **NavigationCacheMode** which will cache your previous navigation. So, `OnNavigatedTo` will not be triggered.

You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode)